# How to find minimum element in a given range of indices for a vector?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, stdvector, minimum

How to find the minimum element in a given range of indices for a `std::vector`?

Let us say the vector is

```
vector<int> v = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

So

```
min_element(v.begin(), v.end());
```

will give `1`.

But what if we want a minimum from indices `1` to `3`?

That is, in the elements `{2,3,4}` of `v`, which is `2`.

Answer (score 10):

Since the `std::min_element` runs in the range `[first, last)`(from `first` till one past `end`), we need to provide as per:

```
const auto begin = v.begin() + 1;
const auto end = begin + 3;
int min = *std::min_element(begin, end);
```

or use [`std::next`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next) to make it generic(credits @Slava)

```
auto min = *std::min_element(std::next(v.begin(), 1), std::next(v.begin(), 4));
```

To wrap it in a helper function:

```
template<typename Container, typename Predicate = std::less<>>
auto min_element(
    const Container &container,
    std::size_t startIdx,
    std::size_t endIdx,
    const Predicate pred = {}) -> std::decay_t<decltype(*(container.begin()))>
                               // typename Container::value_type   // or simply
{
    return *std::min_element(std::next(container.begin(), startIdx),
                             std::next(container.begin(), ++endIdx), pred);
}
```

now in the main

```
std::vector<int> v = { 1, 3, 5, 2, 1 };
const auto startIndex = 1u, endIndex = 3u;
const int min = ::min_element(v, startIndex, endIndex /*, predicate if any*/);
```

**[See a live example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/qBX4AQYYHGO99nK6)**

---

However, ensure that the given iterators are valid, otherwise the behavior is UB.

Comment: Using `std::next()` instead of + would make it more generic.

Comment: The end iterator of `min_element()` is not inclusive, just like with most other algorithms. So, to include index 3 in the searched elements, you need to pass in `begin+4` as the end iterator, not `begin+3`.  Otherwise, use `first = begin+1, end = first+3; min_element(first, end)`

Comment: v.begin() + start, v.begin+end would also be more generic ;)

Comment: The second argument of `min_element()` is one past the end, not the end.   So should be `+4` not `+3` to answer the question as asked.

Comment: The "following exceptions" amount to throwing an exception if comparing elements throws, or if a memory allocation fails.   Neither of those are related to validity of iterators - they are related to the algorithm used.   The behaviour is actually undefined if the iterators are invalid (e.g. in different containers).